# Google spreadsheets. Do something when cell contains E-mail Adress

Tags: excel, email, google-sheets

I've got a cell which could contain an E-mail address, plain text (not an E-mail address) or be empty. If the cell contains an E-mail address I want to copy everyting in that cell to a diffrent cell, and when it doesn't contain an E-mail adress I want to copy that text to another diffrent cell (diffrent form both the E-mail cell and the original cell). If it's empty I don't want to do anyting. How would I achieve this?

[It would look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEU8E.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single function in google sheets - using regexextract - the nifty thing is that you can put a single function in only one column, you can construct an if statement that pushes the non email to the next column when that is the case:

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\w+@\w+"),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\s?(.*@.*)\s?"),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\s?)(.*)"))
```

To explain the regexmatch  - `\w+` means one of more of any word or number followed by an `@` sign and another `\w+` this is just a check to make sure there is an email value somewhere in the text - if that returns true that it takes grabs the email (which can actually have any characters because we change to `.*` which means 0 or more of any character.

Google sheets uses capture groups, so in the `else` part of the statement we tell it to put either a space or nothing in the first cell and push the non email text to the second by surround `.*` with parentheses in our second capture group.

I know that might be a little confusing but it works and with a little research on regexes you will find they are incredibly dynamic and useful - I use them every day

[image]

Also this only works in google sheets - not excel - but since you had the tag ...

Comment: Hi! Thanks this is what I was looking for. Can I ask you what the "\s?" does? Also if I wanted to flip the cells (so the cell "Is email" is in collum C and "not email" in colum B) what would I have to do to the expressions? I guess I don't understand how you push the the non email to the next cell.

Comment: sheets separates every `capture group` to its own cell  - so the double parentheses creates two capture groups - if you wanted to swap them you would just swap your if statement portions to `=if(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\w+@\w+")),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\s?)(.*)"),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\s?(.*@.*)\s?"))`

Comment: Also `\s` means space and the question mark suggest there might be a space but there also might not be a space

Answer (score 0):

This formula should be in column B (email):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("@";A1));A1;"")
```

And this formula should be in column C (text):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("@";A1));"";IF(A1<>"";A1;""))
```

Basically it will look for an @ sign and if there is an @ it's an email.
If there is not an @ it will look at the cell and make sure it's not empty.
(notice I used column C and D, but that does not change anything.)

[image]